# xpath: check if <title> is in first <section> of <body>

Tags: xpath

I have an XML with the following structure:

```
<document>
<body>
<section>
<section>
<title>This is a title (this is the element we want to highlight)</title>
<p>This is some content</p>
</section>
<section>
<title>Another title</title>
<p>More content</p>
</section>
</section>
<section>
<section>
<title>Another title</title>
<p>This is some content</p>
</section>
<section>
<title>Another title</title>
<p>More content</p>
</section>
</section>
</body>
</document>
```

I am trying to figure out an Xpath-expression that marks the first title in the first section in section in body (document/body/section[1]/section[1]/title) but i cant get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you get it to work, it seems to work just fine: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/fd69f8a9e9b29cd56e88f40369c59e1d

Comment: A bit different: `(document/body/section/section//title)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your xpath is fine. However, I suspect of a namespace. Try the following:

```
*:document/*:body/*:section[1]/*:section[1]/*:title
```

Comment: It seems the namespace is fine. The problem is that my xpath (at least in my XML editor) marks the second section as well ((document/body/section[2]/section[2]/title)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. If anyone is in need of a similar solution, this worked for me:

```
count(../../preceding-sibling::node())+1=1
```